# Merge request of two almost-identical answers

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates, specific-answer

The answers https://math.stackexchange.com/a/831870/290189 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/831830/290189 contain the same math equations with the same variables.  The logic is the same, only the paragraph in the middle differs.

1. Can we keep either the older or the newer version?
2. Can we merge the comments into one thread?

Comment: Typically, merges are limited to questions: when two questions are well written and  and both have answers, the questions can be merged by a moderator, into one question which collects all answers posted on the two initial questions.

Comment: Trusted users can vote to delete answer with negative net vote.

Answer (score 0):

(Update)

The newer answer has been mod-deleted, while the older one is untouched.